# Can't register new users on default MVC4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In one of my controllers I'm trying to assign the user that's logged into my application to a ticket:

```
   public ActionResult Create(TicketVM model)   
    {


        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }

        Ticket ticket = new Ticket
        {
            UserID = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
            Issue = model.Issue,
            IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
            CategoryID = model.CategoryID
        };

            db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

However when I click on Register on the default MVC application I get this error

> The connection string 'DefaultConnection' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

I'm fairly certain it's because I didn't link my "UserContext"(Context with the DB of my usernames and passwords). I've seen it before in "SQL SerVer Object Explorer" under Databases\Your Context\Tables but it's missing now.

```
Line 32:                     using (var context = new UsersContext())
Line 33:                     {
Line 34:                         if (!context.Database.Exists()) <--- ERROR HERE
Line 35:                         {
Line 36:                             // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
```

Filters\InitializeSimpleMemberShipAttribute.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models;

namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

AccountModels(UserContext)

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Models
{
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocalPasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalLogin
    {
        public string Provider { get; set; }
        public string ProviderDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string ProviderUserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
namespace RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/Login

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Login

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LogOff

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Register

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Register

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Attempt to register the user
                try
                {
                    WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Disassociate

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Disassociate(string provider, string providerUserId)
        {
            string ownerAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.GetUserName(provider, providerUserId);
            ManageMessageId? message = null;

            // Only disassociate the account if the currently logged in user is the owner
            if (ownerAccount == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                // Use a transaction to prevent the user from deleting their last login credential
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable }))
                {
                    bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
                    if (hasLocalAccount || OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name).Count > 1)
                    {
                        OAuthWebSecurity.DeleteAccount(provider, providerUserId);
                        scope.Complete();
                        message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
                    }
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = message });
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/Manage

        public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
        {
            ViewBag.StatusMessage =
                message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
                : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
                : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
                : "";
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/Manage

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Manage(LocalPasswordModel model)
        {
            bool hasLocalAccount = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = hasLocalAccount;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
            if (hasLocalAccount)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather than return false in certain failure scenarios.
                    bool changePasswordSucceeded;
                    try
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        changePasswordSucceeded = false;
                    }

                    if (changePasswordSucceeded)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // User does not have a local password so remove any validation errors caused by a missing
                // OldPassword field
                ModelState state = ModelState["OldPassword"];
                if (state != null)
                {
                    state.Errors.Clear();
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        WebSecurity.CreateAccount(User.Identity.Name, model.NewPassword);
                        return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("Unable to create local account. An account with the name \"{0}\" may already exist.", User.Identity.Name));
                    }
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLogin

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
        {
            return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
            if (!result.IsSuccessful)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // If the current user is logged in add the new account
                OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
                string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
                ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string provider = null;
            string providerUserId = null;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Insert a new user into the database
                using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
                {
                    UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == model.UserName.ToLower());
                    // Check if user already exists
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        // Insert name into the profile table
                        db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile { UserName = model.UserName });
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, providerUserId, model.UserName);
                        OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, createPersistentCookie: false);

                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.");
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Account/ExternalLoginFailure

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginFailure()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult ExternalLoginsList(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return PartialView("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", OAuthWebSecurity.RegisteredClientData);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult RemoveExternalLogins()
        {
            ICollection<OAuthAccount> accounts = OAuthWebSecurity.GetAccountsFromUserName(User.Identity.Name);
            List<ExternalLogin> externalLogins = new List<ExternalLogin>();
            foreach (OAuthAccount account in accounts)
            {
                AuthenticationClientData clientData = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(account.Provider);

                externalLogins.Add(new ExternalLogin
                {
                    Provider = account.Provider,
                    ProviderDisplayName = clientData.DisplayName,
                    ProviderUserId = account.ProviderUserId,
                });
            }

            ViewBag.ShowRemoveButton = externalLogins.Count > 1 || OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
            return PartialView("_RemoveExternalLoginsPartial", externalLogins);
        }

        #region Helpers
        private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        public enum ManageMessageId
        {
            ChangePasswordSuccess,
            SetPasswordSuccess,
            RemoveLoginSuccess,
        }

        internal class ExternalLoginResult : ActionResult
        {
            public ExternalLoginResult(string provider, string returnUrl)
            {
                Provider = provider;
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            }

            public string Provider { get; private set; }
            public string ReturnUrl { get; private set; }

            public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
            {
                OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication(Provider, ReturnUrl);
            }
        }

        private static string ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus createStatus)
        {
            // See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=177550 for
            // a full list of status codes.
            switch (createStatus)
            {
                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName:
                    return "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateEmail:
                    return "A user name for that e-mail address already exists. Please enter a different e-mail address.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidPassword:
                    return "The password provided is invalid. Please enter a valid password value.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidEmail:
                    return "The e-mail address provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidAnswer:
                    return "The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidQuestion:
                    return "The password retrieval question provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.InvalidUserName:
                    return "The user name provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError:
                    return "The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                case MembershipCreateStatus.UserRejected:
                    return "The user creation request has been canceled. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";

                default:
                    return "An unknown error occurred. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.";
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `connectionString` does not seem to have provider name:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
```

Your app needs to know what kind of data provider it is connected to. For `SQL Server`, add the `providerName` as `System.Data.SqlClient`:

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

like this

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And it should OK.

Comment: Yeah it's working now Thanks ! What happens if my connectionstring isn't going to a SQL server but a localdb? Do we use `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`?

Comment: @JasonWan hmm.. I am not to sure about that.. but if you have localdb as `Oracle` (in my case, localdb is not `Oracle`, but I once use `Oracle` database) then probably you got to provide the correct provider name (in my case, since I use ODP.Net `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`, I have to put the provider name as `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`) - something along that line -probably.